# Do subsequent question-bans make escaping the Void harder?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions, post-ban

I've had a question ban for at least a month, ever since I was on 470 reputation, so I'm pretty deep into the Void.

I *did* ask some bad questions which got me caught in a question-ban before. However, one of my answers were upvoted after this which kicked me out of the question-ban (after posting about it on Meta). Sod's Law obviously dictated that someone had to *downvote* one of my questions, which pushed me back into the question-ban.

That was at least a month ago.

I have since gained around 60 reputation (mostly for reviews, but also for upvotes on answers I've given), but with no change in the question-ban.

This has made me think; ***do subsequent question-bans make it harder for the question-ban to be lifted?***

*I wouldn't be too surprised, but a time-expiry should apply here as I've been pretty active for the past month with question reviews, flags, comments, and helping new users (and also the occasional answer). I personally think I've done more than enough to have my question-ban lifted.*
I am aware that I *could* request my downvoted deleted questions be dissociated with my account, but I don't have a good justification for this.

I've even gone as far as writing out a message to the Stack Exchange staff requesting the dissociation, but I'm acutely aware that they probably get a few of the same requests every single day. As a result I've decided not to send the message as I don't want to waste anybody's time here.

*To clarify, this is the message I receive when trying to post a question:*

[image]

I've started using another website (*gasp!*) for my programming questions, but the answers I've been getting are nowhere near the quality of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Plus one unit of support for *the Void*. And because the question is interesting, and I think divulging information about this will not really help would-be abusers (if anything, it would be more of a deterrent).

Comment: Do you have a bunch of deleted questions?  Your account looks good.  If only there was a way to, I dunno, "disassociate" bad questions from accounts...

Comment: @Will I have 5 or 6, but all were posted before my first question-ban, so I don't think these ones have much influence.
The only way to disassociate questions from accounts is to get the Stack Exchange staff to do it; it's something that even moderators can't even do, which is the reason I haven't yet accepted Servy's answer. I know the Stack Exchange employees monitor [tag:support] and [tag:bug] and I'll wait a couple of days to see if any of them reply.

Comment: There was one _heavily_ downvoted (deleted) question that was dragging you down - that was what made things really hard here. I've disassociated it from your account now. Go forth and ask good questions!

Comment: The Void.   Is that anything like a write-only file?

Comment: I think the interesting question would have been how much more reputation cybermonkey would have needed to get himself out of the ban without moderation intervention? Maybe one should show this information to the people having a question ban. "You are question-banned, gain approximately XX additional reputation and we let you ask questions again." With this I mean that usually a convict is told what the detention is. Leaving him in the dark about the scale of the work he has to do could be seen as overly mean treatment.

Comment: @Trilarion It's got nothing to do with reputation, but is a calculation from deleted questions/downvotes/negative actions. Whilst I agree with your suggestion, implementing it *could* lead to users finding out the 'secret calculation'. ***As of now I am no longer question banned***, I don't even see the `warning, you have asked too many recent low-quality questions and are in danger of being blocked from asking any more`, thanks to the community on Meta :-).

Comment: What other website?

Comment: @PeterMortensen cplusplus.com. I know it's a forum which none of the Stack Exchange sites are, however it's still horrible to use.

Comment: @cybermonkey I think it must have to do something with reputation at least loosely relate to it. Maybe a range of reputation gain or a number of other actions can be indicated. As it is you never know how long the ban might endure. One month is maybe okay if you know how long it will take approximately or what is needed approximately. If you don't give out the exact values nobody will find out the secret formula.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.  That's not how it works.  Whenever you try to post a question, at that point in time, a "score" is calculated based on the contributions you've made.  If that score is high enough, you're allowed to post.  If it's not, you can't.  Having gone above or below that score in the past doesn't make the score go even lower.

Comment: Can you cite your sources? I thought the implementation details of the ban algorithm were kept secret for a good reason :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi We don't know how the actual score is calculated.  *That* is what's a secret.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi AFAIK the only secret alghoritm is the one dealing with serial voting. The banning and throttling ones should be clearly described somewhere to anyone.

Comment: @Servy, but do we really know the "unban threshold" is not increased in every ban? I never read anything about this on Meta (then again I can't read everything).

Comment: @Renan No, SE has been quite clear that they're not going to divulge the specifics of the question ban algorithm.  They've given out some high level details, but not enough to actual calculate it yourself.

Comment: @Renan No, those are secret too. We don't want people staying right above the ban threshold.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi We know that, contrary to the name, it's not actually a "ban".  It calculates the value *when you go to ask a question*.  If you dip below the threshold and then back up again without asking a question, the system would have never known or kept track of the fact that you couldn't ask a question during that time.  It doesn't remember your ban history because there *is* no ban history.  It is strictly a set of quality criteria for being able to ask a question.

Comment: @Servy, so it's a computed state, not a stored flag. I suppose that would indeed make a varying threshold pretty much impossible... assuming *nothing else* is stored (e.g. a simple count of the times you went under the threshold). And we probably won't have access to that kind of information :)

Comment: Any idea what this score might be set by? Reviews? Edits? Comments? Flags? I've done a significant amount of all of them with no effect. I've got a feeling that *only* providing upvoted answers to questions can do it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi To keep track of that would mean it'd need to go around computing this value for every user, constantly.  That would be a *ton* of work.  As it is, the system only ever computes the value when you try to ask a question, and since it's (presumably) pretty complex, doing otherwise is not likely to be practical.

Comment: @Servy, I don't get your *constantly*. User attempts to post => server computes score => server increases counter if score is below the threshold. Looks like on-demand to me.

Comment: @cybermonkey It's been stated that votes on posts are considered, along with closures, and deletions.  That's about all that's public.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi So you'd punish people for trying to post when they can't, but not punish them for just not trying to post when below the threshold?  That doesn't really make sense.  I mean, yes, that's something that they *could* do; it's feasible, but I see no reason why they would want to.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi What you described [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277472/do-subsequent-question-bans-make-escaping-the-void-harder/277473?noredirect=1#comment120113_277473) would mean that it's only recording a "ban" if the user tries to post when below the threshold, thus pushing them further into the hole.  If they would have just not tried to post the question it wouldn't have computed the value, and not pushed them further into the hole.  Digging them deeper into the hole just for *failing to post a new question* doesn't seem like something you'd want to do.

Comment: @Servy, hmm, you're absolutely right. We would also have to store the fact the user went above the threshold. Maybe a delta between two running counters, but it's true it makes less and less sense the more I think of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what servy said in his answer - you should work to improve your existing questions and answers. New negative votes on them will count against you, so it is preferable that you address whatever problems they have in to avoid getting more downvotes.