# Does earning large amounts of reputation directly affect a question ban?

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

I have recently been browsing around in the help center, and just a few days ago was reading the post about question bans. The post clearly stated that to aid in getting out of a question ban, one must positively contribute to the Stack Overflow site. I then wondered if the banning algorithm took a users reputation level into account.

I know that having high reputation, or earning large amounts of reputation, does not necessarily mean you've gotten better at asking questions. But it seems to me that on Stack Overflow reputation is not easily gotten by any means (excluding of course serial up-voters). So reputation, to a certain degree, could be used to measure a given users "positive contributions".

To give an example of what I mean, let's just say that User A has been question banned with currently 50 reputation points. Over the course of a month or so, User A earns 450 reputation points (including the bonus awarded at 100 reputation points):

- Is User A any closer to getting out of the question ban?
- Would what User A has done be considered positive contribution?

The above is a very specific example, and is just meant to serve illustrative purposes. But the example could very well be applied in the real world.

To summarize my question: Does earning large amounts of reputation (or any for that matter), play any part all in escaping the infamous question ban?

---

My question is **not** a duplicate of [Do subsequent question-bans make escaping the Void harder?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277472/do-subsequent-question-bans-make-escaping-the-void-harder) because I'm asking **whether gained reputation during a question ban will directly affect the question ban**, while the other question is asking **whether or not a previous question ban will affect your current one**.

Comment: repulsion level… that's a funny typo ;o) [fixed]

Comment: from what i understand from reading [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/1028804) a question ban just stops you posting and is invisible to others. if someone under a question ban didn't have rep changes from votes then it wouldn't be invisible while a suspensions does block rep again

Comment: Here's a tip: Since you're asking about how does the site work (in some way), you should tag this question with [support](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support).

Comment: Also helpful http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/86998#86998

Comment: @Mr.goosberry how specific (and detailed) of an answer are you looking for? The simple answer is "yes, it is a positive contribution and it helps get out of the ban". But no one can provide any more detail since the exact algorithm is secret (those who know won't tell, and those who don't know can only guess from available info)

Answer (score 14):

**TL;DR:** Personal experience says no, gaining reputation does not directly affect a question ban.

[On the help page for question bans](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), it says the following:

> **How can I get out of a question ban?**
>
> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines
>   that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were
>   poorly received.

[image: My account's reputation over time]

With that being said, personal experience has led me to believe that  ***earning reputation has little to no effect on a question ban***.

---

My Stack Overflow account was question banned on February 17th, 2017. Admittedly at the time, the ban was deserved. I was a novice on SO, and had submitted some admittedly low quality questions. I had submitted 8 questions, 7 of which had a score of 0 or lower. My account had a reputation of around 30. ([For reference, my question history as of April 17, 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFON7.png)).

Since then, over the past 3 months my rep has [increased from 30 to 414](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74Iov.png), putting me in the top 7% of contributors this year. However, the question ban for SO still remains in place. This leads me to believe positive contributions are measured in some other way.

[image: "You have reached your question limit"]

---

**Edit: [TFW you may have just been unquestion banned because you posted an answer claiming that answering questions can't get you unquestioned banned.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333698/does-earning-large-amounts-of-reputation-directly-affect-a-question-ban/348029#comment466294_348029)**

Comment: Like the quoted help center says, `The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were poorly received.`  That you earned a few hundred rep doesn't mean that your positive contributions outweigh your negative contributions.  You can earn a few hundred rep and still have *dramatically* more (and more serious) negative contributions than you have positive contributions.

Comment: Rep is of course a very *poor* means of evaluating the sum of your contributions; upvotes give *much* more rep than downvotes remove, rep doesn't incorporate closure/deletion (in fact, the reverse, as deleted low quality content *removes* the rep penalty, despite it still being a negative site contribution).  That said, while rep is a poor measure of the sum quality of your contributions, that doesn't change the fact that the types of things that earn you rep *are* positive site contributions.

Comment: @Servy I agree that rep is a poor way to judge quality. That's why I'm stating I don't think rep is that much of a factor for reversing question bans

Comment: Kudos for continuing to contribute in spite of the ban.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Again, *the help center tells you what's going on here".  The ban will last "until your positive contributions outweigh your negative contributions".  That you've earned some rep doesn't mean that that's the case, nor is the question ban going to look at your rep; it's going to look at your positive and negative contributions.

Comment: @Servy I've rephrased my answer as to not accuse the help center article of being misleading.

Comment: Probably best to think about this as "positive contributions affect rep. positive contributions also affect q-ban." - IOW, they're not *directly* tied, but the same inputs affect both. Also, good answer - needs more freehand red circles. P.P.S. you're not currently q-banned.